# How to output api response for nested object in PHP and curl?

Tags: php, api, curl

Am trying to post to an endpoint URL using curl and PHP but am not getting a response only getting error 404 and null. Just following some API documentation on the web

this is my php code

```
<?php
$jsonString = [
    "identifier" => "ghgfhgf",
    "currency" => "USD",
    "amount" => "50",
    "details" => "pen",
    "ipn_url" => "https://script.viserlab.com/paymenthub/ipn_url.php",
    "success_url" => "https://script.viserlab.com/paymenthub/test-api/success.php",
    "cancel_url" => "https://script.viserlab.com/paymenthub/test-api/failed.php",
    "site_name" => "fwew332",
    "public_key" => "pro_zlzdbehyqspvehw427tw2ia7nxpu9z4vj9g36x6y1kj64mgg0t1",
    "customer" => [
        "first_name" => "John",
        "last_name" => "Doe",
        "email" => "johndoe@example.com",
        "mobile" => "555-555-5555"
    ]
];

$jsonString = http_build_query($jsonString);

$jsonData = json_decode($jsonString); // Encode the JSON data as a string
$endpoint = "https://script.viserlab.com/paymenthub/payment/initiate";

$curl = curl_init($endpoint); // Initialize cURL session
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint); // Set the URL for the request
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); // Set the request type to POST
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData); // Set the JSON data as the request body
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Return the response as a string

// For debug purposes only! Disable SSL verification (remove in production)
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$response = curl_exec($curl); // Execute the cURL request
curl_close($curl); // Close the cURL session

echo $response; // Display the response
?>
```

response from API should look like this

```
//Error Response.
{
    "status": "error",
    "message": [
        "Not Paid"
    ]
}

//Success Response.
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": [
        "Paid"
    ],
    "redirect_url": "https://example.com/payment/checkout"
}
```

but my PHP side of the code doesn't output the response

Answer (score 0):

1. `http_build_query()` has *nothing* to do with JSON, and notably turns the data into a HTTP query string, *not* JSON.
2. `json_decode()`, as the name implies, *decodes* JSON. This is the opposite of encoding.

   - This should also generate an error message where you've used it. Turn `error_reporting` on/up when you are writing new code so that you can actually *see* them.

You likely want to replace:

```php
$jsonString = http_build_query($jsonString);
$jsonData = json_decode($jsonString);
```

With:

```
$jsonData = json_encode($jsonString);
```

and if you're still having trouble then you'll need to refer to your API provider's docs.

Also, just for the sake of readability, consider swapping your `$jsonString` and `$jsonData` variable names, as they are named the opposite of what they actually contain.

Comment: I replaced it as you said and turn on error reporting, but all I get now is a blank page, the $response is returning null. When I use Postman it returns the response but when I use Curl it returns null